# dplyr::pull with a bare or quoted string as an argument?

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on reading the [documentation](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html) of `dplyr::pull` and examining the examples, I am under the impression that the `var` argument should be a "bare column name". For example:

```
dplyr::pull(mtcars, cyl)
[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

However, I just realized that a quoted column name works too:

```
dplyr::pull(mtcars, "cyl")
[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

I am just curious as to whether there are any differences between these two styles. Moreover, are there any downsides of using the second option for say non-interactive usage (e.g. R package development).

I have using version 0.7.4 of dplyr in these examples.

Thanks

Comment: which version of `dplyr` are you referring to? I ask because things look a bit different now with `tidyselect`

Comment: @RolandASc Sorry I should have mentioned that in the original post. I am using version 0.7.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pull` calls `select_var` which uses [quasiquotation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.1.6/topics/quasiquotation) to evaluate or not the argument and eventually return a column name from the data. This allows the column to be specified in a flexible way that supports both interactive and programming use.

```
a <- "cyl"
select_var(names(mtcars), a)
[1] "cyl"
pull(mtcars,a)
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```